# Correct way of authentication with different hashes?

Tags: php

I'm using the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to perform user authentication, with bcrypt as algorithm.

Because I now create different hashes each time, I can't compare the hash directly in my database with an sql `WHERE password = :hash`

So now my sql statement is as follows: `SELECT username, password FROM Users WHERE username = :username`, followed by the `password_verify()` method.

Now my big question is, is it safe to fetch a password hash with only the given username?

I guess I'm over-concerned, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you are over concerned. either way the hash is being passed between the database server and the application server, and stored some where in memory. with the first example the hash is generated on the application side and transmitted to the database, on the second the hash is queried and returned.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the user names are *unique* in the database, sure. You will want to ensure you're not falling prey to any collation logic, e.g. your username is "grég" but gets matched by "greg" in the database. For this, either restrict the characters a username may consist of and/or use a `_bin` collation on the column.

Other than that, nothing changes as long as you handle the next step, the password comparison in the PHP code, correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the collation tip! Haven't thought of that yet.